# Bullet Points Positioning with Arabic RTL direction

Tags: html, css, internationalization

I am using custom bullet points on a website.
Now this site will also be available in Arabic.

```
.post ul li{
    color: #555555;
    background: url(images/ico-bullet_round.gif) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 300px 6px !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
    padding-left:0 !important;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

However with *direction:rtl;* I am unable to have all the bullet points on the right side. Some are more indented than others.

[Please see a screenshot showing the problem.](http://h-3.abload.de/img/arabic_bullet_pointsth62.jpg)

Any suggestions on how to simply align all bullet points on the right?

UPDATE: Please see this screenshot with *background-position* set to 0 6px. It has something to do with *direction:rtl;* but I can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you want to specify directionality via CSS. Have you tried to assign dir="rtl" attribute to enclosing tag (the one that contains your unordered list)? I think it could resolve your issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there any reason why not simply `list-style-image`, which is designed specifically for custom bullets?

```
ul { margin: 0 20px; padding: 0; }
ul li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style: disc url(images/ico-bullet_round.gif);
    direction:rtl;
}
```

works for me, assuming you do mean the right-hand side when you say “right side”. You could have them on the left as well if you wanted by putting the `rtl` on a child div inside the li, but that'd look a bit strange for Arabic, I think.

Comment: Excellent answer, I didn't know that you could use list-style with custom images. Thank you! Works fine!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got over it by using:

```
ul{direction:rtl;}
li{direction:rtl; margin-right:20px;}
```

The functioning attribute is using: `margin-right:20px while using direction :rtl`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to put background-position like this:
 background-position: 100% 6px !important;

I supppose that the direction: rtl, does not influence in backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using `&bull;` at the beginning of the sentence, while aligning everything to the right. That way you can get something like this:

مرحبا •

Answer (score 1):

Try ::before and ::after in css styling and your rtl file and use JavaScript to release css effect.

Example:

[this is (RTL list but bullets are not suitable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcpbz.jpg)

Here are you Css code for before RTL.

```css
ul.points li:before{content:"\f0c8";font-family:fontawesome;color:#135588;margin-right:7px;font-size:.75em}
```

Then After i made RTL file i used this code :

```css
ul.points li:after{content:"\f0c8";font-family:fontawesome;color:#135588;margin-right:7px;font-size:.75em}
```

but look for this image ( it has bullets before and after ( hence your turn to remover it using javascript (add class and remove class) to Css:
[this is (after) rtl css style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPcIE.jpg)

I wish this helps noting that it's my first comment in stack ever!

Answer (score -1):

Try background-position: right;

Worked for me.